# How do I create a numpy N-dimensional array of zeros, with only a single element equal to one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a short, one-line way to create numpy array (which may have several dimensions) which has one in a certain position, and zeros in all the others? For the 1-D array, one can do the following to create an array with a 1 on k^{th} position:

```
np.eye(1, N, k = k)
```

How can this be generalized to the higher-dimensional case?

Comment: So if the array is not 1-d, where os the one and where the 0 ? Is the one unique at first position, of first position of every last-dimension array. Please give example

Comment: ...a "cute" way?

Comment: @azro something like this : np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]) - the only one nonzero element is located at [0, 2]. In general, if the array is N-dimensional, all posititons, except some [i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n] are zero, and in this position there is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if you need a 3x5 matrix with the 1 at index (2, 3), just make a 1D array, then reshape it:

```
M, N = 3, 5
i, j = 2, 3
np.eye(1, M * N, k=(i+1) * M + j).reshape(M, N)

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

It may help to know that *every* multi-dimensional numpy array is internally represented as a 1D array, with some wrapper logic to handle strides and indexing. That means this solution here can also generalise to any dimension with the appropriate arithmetic. Here's a generalization:

```
def make_nd_array_with(dims, index):
    return (np.eye(1, 
                   np.prod(dims), 
                   k=(((np.array(index[:-1]) + 1) * dims[:-1]).sum() + index[-1]))
              .reshape(*dims))

make_nd_array_with((M,N), (i,j))

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Note that this addresses your constraint of wanting to do this in a single line, but the generally canonical solution is to create an array of zeros and set a single value, as the comments and [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62705375/4909087) mentions.

```
arr = np.zeros(M, N)
arr[i, j] = 1
```

Comment: Note that this assumes row major ordering for calculating indices.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `eye` or `reshape`, it's **much, much clearer** to just write a function that calls `zeros` and sets the element you want:

```
def mostly_zeros(shape, nonzero_position, dtype=float, nonzero_element=1):
    retval = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    retval[nonzero_index] = nonzero_element
    return retval
```

Then you can call `mostly_zeros(shape=(4, 5), nonzero_position=(2, 2))` to get a mostly-zero array of shape `(4, 5)` with a `1.0` at position `(2, 2)`. This will be a lot less of a maintenance headache than `eye`.

---

Alternatively, you could write a function that sets items and returns the array:

```
def chainable_setitem(obj, index, val):
    obj[index] = val
    return obj
```

Then you can do `chainable_setitem(numpy.zeros((4, 5)), (2, 2), 1)` to get a 4x5 array with a 1.0 at position 2, 2 and zeros elsewhere.

Comment: This is clearly the canonical answer, the op added a constraint to do this in a single line which my answer addresses. But this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for a one-liner:

```
np.bincount([np.ravel_multi_index(pos,shp)],None,np.prod(shp)).reshape(shp)
```

Example

```
shp = 3,4
pos = 1,2
np.bincount([np.ravel_multi_index(pos,shp)],None,np.prod(shp)).reshape(shp)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Admittedly this is much better for 1D where it simplifies to

```
np.bincount([pos],None,length)
```

than for nD

Comment: For 1D case looks better using `np.eye`: `np.eye(<N>)[<pos>]`